# Network is slow after promoting the secondary domain controller and deleting the old primary domain controller

Tags: networking, dns, domain

We have recently promoted our secondary domain controller to be primary. The roles were transferred without errors etc. We then deleted the former primary controller. Everything seems to work ok, however, the network is quite slow. It takes a long time to transfer files and open access databases.

We've removed references to the old DC in the DNS manager and from all servers and clients DNS settings.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be the cause?